# does onDraw in a surfaceview container causes video to be invalidated?

Tags: android, optimization, surfaceview, android-videoview, hardware-acceleration

I have a **video view**. This view is contained inside a custom `FrameLayout` called `VideoStructure`, where I can put also a channel logo or things alike.
[image]
Under normal conditions, the video is hardware accelerated, so the view is (i suppose) really a transparent "black hole", while the video is decoded & rendered by the relevant hardware.

My question is, if I override `draw()`  in the Video View's container (the `VideoStructure` extends `FrameLayout` in the image) to draw some stuff (ie. the circle in the image) **OVER** the video -I'm overriding `draw()`, not `onDraw()`- will this break the hardware acceleration? Can I expect a big performance hit for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should have no effect on performance.

SurfaceViews have two parts, the "view" part, and the "surface" part.  The "view" part is a transparent hole that fits in with the other views, the "surface" part is a completely independent layer that is composited with the view layer by the system.  The video is being sent to the "surface" part.

If you override SurfaceView's "view" renderer, you'll get a hardware-accelerated Canvas for a View that is normally completely transparent (so if you erase it, you better use an alpha of zero and the correct transfer mode).

If you attempt to render on the "surface" part, by getting a Canvas from `lockCanvas()`, you will either fail (because the video effectively has it locked), or succeed and prevent video from being written to it.

The system compositor is going to have to blend the "view" and "surface" layers no matter what appears in the "view" layer, so making a few more pixels opaque isn't going to have a measurable impact.

**Update:** see the [graphics architecture doc](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html) for more details on Surfaces and composition.

Comment: oohh what an accurate explanation, just what I wanted to know!

Comment: @fadden - I know this is an old answer but it come up in searches and is very detailed as rupps notes, so a quick follow on question: How do we interpret the onDraw method - is it called when the 'view' part or the 'surface' part in your answer is drawn to (or both)? I am guessing it may be the case that the system compositor has to blend the view and the video with every video frame written and this is why, as discussed elsewhere, you can calculate the video framerate by looking at the View's onDraw?

Comment: The app framework calls `onDraw()` when the View is invalidated. It's not called on video updates. Bear in mind that the View UI and video are rendering into separate sets of graphic buffers, both of which are fed to the system compositor (the former by the app, the latter by the video codec in the mediaserver process). You can't calculate the video frame rate from `onDraw()` unless you're decoding the video in software and issuing an invalidate request for every frame.

Comment: Good explanation, especially the note about separate graphic buffers (I'll have to work my way through the doc you linked above...).